# IF multiple criteria matches from two different sheets, return corresponding column value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm using the below IF function to return a corresponding qty using multiple criteria:

`=IF(SKU = SKU Range & Price = Price Range,Qty Range,Qty Range)`

Instead of returning the qty values that match the criteria I specified, the function is returning random #'s. I've also tried this function:

`=INDEX(SKU Range,MATCH(SKU,QTY Range))`

But it only returns the header text as opposed to the qty cell value. Can anyone help with this?

Sheet I want to return qty value using the (SKU/PRICE) criteria

[image]

Sheet I'm matching criteria against and want to pull qty value from

[image]

Comment: If the combonation of sku and price is unique then you can use SUMIFS: `SUMIFS(Qty Range,SKU Range,SKU,Price Range,Price)`

Comment: With your formula, it's returning values, but not the correct ones. As an example, below are screenshots of the formula returning the incorrect data:
Criteria Sheet:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNuW1.png
Array Sheet:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXC09.png

Comment: Some of the combos (SKU/PRICE) from the array sheet are unique, but not all.

Comment: How do you know which one to pick if/when they are not unique?

Comment: @MattStapleton, you mean to say if Formula finds SKU Name & Price of Sheet 1 into Sheet 2 has to return the Quantity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I would like to suggest two possible solutions. First one finds single Quantity based on SKU and Price and Second method returns multiple Quantities when match with SKU & Price between Sheets.*

[image]

**Method 1:**

- Enter `SKU` & `Price` in `Sheet1` cell `A10` & `B10` and enter this Array (CSE) Formula in Cell `C10`, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$8,MATCH(1,(A$10=Sheet2!$A$2:$A$8)*(B$10=Sheet2!$B$2:$B$8),0)),"")}
  ```

**Method 2:**

- Enter `SKU` & `Price` in `Sheet1` cell `A15` & `B15` and enter this Array (CSE) Formula in Cell `C15`, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill it down.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$8, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($A$15, Sheet2!$A$2:$A$8)*COUNTIF($B$15, Sheet2!$B$2:$B$8), ROW(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$8)-MIN(ROW(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$8))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1)),"")}
  ```

**N.B.**

*Adjust Cell references in both Formulas as needed.*

Comment: This worked ty!

Comment: Glad to help you @MattStapleton,, keep asking ☺